# comar fazer esse efeito em css

Tags: css

há uma possibilidade de me ajudar implantar este código 
**css**

```css
img {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.capa {
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
}

.cd {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img class="capa" src="http://www.suamusica.com.br/dirs/293980/686110/cd_cover.jpg">
<img class="cd" src="http://www.suamusica.com.br/dirs/293980/686110/cd_cover.jpg">
```

**no meu site? execute o trecho para entender!** **ALGUM CONTATO?**

> http://site.damarciocds.com.br/oz-kara-de-saia-to-solteiro-previa/

Comment: Então se tens o código onde está o problema? É só usar.

Comment: alinhamento com  uma div  é tambem tentei por e nao fucionou muito bem nao ficou redondo!

Comment: a uma possibilidade de vc editar ae pelo inspecionador de elementos do seu browser?  ? e mandar pra me a que para me poder tentar inseri-lo ?

Comment: tens de adaptar ao teu código. Coloca aqui o teu código da div resu-post

Comment: uso esse código para postar o conteúdo talvez de pra adicionar na clas Capa     <div class="Info"><b>Banda:</b>Oz Karaz de Saia <br>
<b>Local:</b>Não Informado<br>
<b>Tamanho:</b>3.08MB<br>
<b>Qualidade:</b>100%<br>
<b>Gravação:</b>Banda/Produção
</div>
<p><!--more--></p>
<div class="Capa">
<img src="http://www.suamusica.com.br/dirs/293980/686110/cd_cover.jpg" height="160" width="160">
<div class="Links"><strong>Servidor Para o Download – <a href="http://www.suamusica.com.br/OzKarazdeSaiaTOSOLTEIRO2015" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"> Sua Musica </a></strong></div>
</div>

Comment: Coloca a função `the_content();` que é onde deves ter o código da div.

Comment: AXO QUE A FUNÇÃO SEJA ESSA QUE POSTEI A CIMA! AXO QUE ADICIONANDO MAIS UMA IMAGEM E EDITANDO A <div class="Capa"> ELA FUNCIONE SO N SEI COMO TEM WATS? PRA VOCE ENTENDER MEU PONTO DE VISTA !

Comment: eu vi esse modelo   nesse site ! http://www.suamusica.com.br/AvioesEmSerraTalhadaSet2015

Comment: Vê a minha resposta.

Comment: não funcionou!   já revisei! http://i.imgur.com/COoFFLM.png

Comment: tem de funcionar, se executares o snipet abaixo funciona.

Comment: funcionar a que funciona mais la no código onde estou tentando implantar não funciona   quando eu coloco o css na style.css acontece isso que esta na foto tem uma div  **.content-single img** por la da pra editar a imagen

Comment: Claro que se tiveres CSS sobreposto vai das asneira. Tens de ir tentando dar um jeito a isso. experimenta ir pondo e tirando regras de CSS

Comment: vou tentar :/ mais confesso que não me dou bem com .css

Comment: alguem???/ ae pra ajudar!

Answer (score 4):

```css
img {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.capa {
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
}

.cd {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Info">
    <b>Banda:</b>Oz Karaz de Saia <br> 
    <b>Local:</b>Não Informado<br>
    <b>Tamanho:</b>3.08MB<br>
    <b>Qualidade:</b>100%<br> 
    <b>Gravação:</b>Banda/Produção </div>
    <p>
        <!--more-->
    </p>
    <div class="Capa">
        <div>
            <img class="capa" src="http://www.suamusica.com.br/dirs/293980/686110/cd_cover.jpg">
            <img class="cd" src="http://www.suamusica.com.br/dirs/293980/686110/cd_cover.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="Links">
            <strong>Servidor Para o Download – 
                <a href="suamusica.com.br/OzKarazdeSaiaTOSOLTEIRO2015"; rel="nofollow" target="_blank"> 
                    Sua Musica 
                </a>
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```